# How to install UEFI Shell and EDK II Linux

Tags: debian, shell, uefi

I have no option for a UEFI shell on my Lenovo U400. I'm triple booting Windows 10, Debian Sid, and FreeBSD 13.0-CURRENT (soon to add macOS Mojave to that) with rEFInd. I want an option for the EFI shell, but my EFI interface (Lenovo 57CN30WW) doesn't have a built-in shell, nor does my EFI partition have a shellx64.efi binary. I heard about the EDK II, but I have no idea how to build it on a Linux system, or a Windows system for that matter. I don't know how to use it exactly either. How would I get an EFI shell up and running on my system, preferably from Debian?

Comment: See if you can directly download a binary shell.efi from https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/UDK2018/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64/Shell.efi. Put it on your EFI partition and create a boot entry pointing to it in your UEFI Setup.

Comment: I did that using efibootmgr on my system, but when I tried to boot to my newly created entry (I put it at the top of my boot order), it simply skipped it and went straight to rEFInd. Can you give specifics on how you would do that, it sounds like something you can put as an answer

Comment: Do you have any option to view/create/update boot entries from within the UEFI Setup of your Lenovo PC?If so, you can check and reset the boot order. Is there any Function key for boot option menu? If yes, you can try selecting the shell.efi boot entry if it has been created therein. I am not much familiar with efibootmgr command and also not too sure what commend you executed. Another option (on Windows) is to use EasyUEFI v2.7 GUI tool to graphically view/edit/modify/delete/set order for boot entries in UEFI from Windows OS.

Comment: Also I assume feature like Secure Boot (If present) that may prevent third party boot loaders is disabled in your UEFI Setup.

Comment: Secure boot is unsupported on my computer; it’s EFI, not UEFI. I used efibootmgr -c -L “UEFI Shell” -l \EFI\Shell.efi to create the entry. Funny thing is, I have no options for UEFI in my BIOS, but I can apparently boot UEFI mode OSes. I will try using EasyUEFI and see how that works.

Comment: Did you try the command efibootmgr -v to get a detailed info about boot entries and check where your shell entry is pointing to? I suggest you try the following way to create boot entry using efibootmgr. Create a folder named shell at \EFI\ put shell.efi therein. So path is \EFI\shell\shell.efi. Now hit the command efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -L "shell" -l \\EFI\\shell\\shell.efi  in this case /dev/sda is the disk and 1 is the partition number of EFI partition. This may vary in your case. fdisk -l to know the disk (Say  /dev/sda) and parted /dev/sda print to know the EFI partition number